# How can I make my bot detect the message AFTER the command prefix?

Tags: python, discord.py

From what I know, the `from discord.ext import commands` works like this:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='John')


@bot.command
async def help(ctx):
      ctx.send.message('help_message')
```

And the bot will send the 'help message' to the channel if I send **John help**.

However, I also want my bot to detect messages using `async def on_message`, and I want it to detect every message, check if it has **John** in it, and if it has **John** in it, to check the rest of the message, and if it is not one of the commands, and it has a certain word, I want it to send a pre-assigned response.

I want it to be something like this:

```
commandlist = ['help','command1','command2','command3']

input = ['Hi','Hello','Sup','Hey'] 

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
      if 'John' in message:
            if all(commandlist) not in message and input in message:
                 await message.channel.send('Hi!')
```

And if I say **John help**, the bot will send the help_message and if I say **Hi John** or **Hey John**, the bot will say **Hi**.

The code above is something like a pseudo-code, so it may have many errors.

Comment: 'AND' replace 'and'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to check the first word of the string sent in the `on_message` decorator.
I would use the str.split() method to get the first word of the string to check if it is equal to John.

```
@bot.event()
async def on_message(message):
   x = message.split(' ', 1)[0]    # This splits the first word of the string
   x = "John":
   while True:
     try:
     if commandlist in message:
        await message.channel.send('Your string')    
         break
     else:
       if input in message:
         await message.channel.send('Other String')
          break
```

I hope this helps with what you needed!

Comment: That solved my problem. Thank you and sorry for checking this late.